# Separate a list of objects into multiple lists that only contain unique items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a requirement in a C# application, that needs to send a list of applications to an api.  the api can take multiple application in one call but there can only be one application per person in the api call.  if a person has more than 1 application in the list it must be removed and sent in it's own call to the api.

The ID is what will be unique for each "person" and what is in the Data does not matter, bob could have 3 applications with data set to "A" and it would still be valid for this example.

here is a basic example of what I mean

I need to go from this, a single list with all applications:

```
{
  [
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Jim', id: 2, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Sam', id: 3, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'B'},
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'C'},
    {name: 'Sam', id: 3, data: 'B'},
    {name: 'Bob', id: 4, data: 'Notice this is a different Bob'}
  ]
}
```

to this, multiple lists that only have one application per person, i.e. bob is in all the lists because he has 3 applications, sam is in 2 of them and jim is just in one.:

```
{
  [
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Jim', id: 2, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Sam', id: 3, data: 'A'},
    {name: 'Bob', id: 4, data: 'Notice this is a different Bob'}
  ],
  [
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'B'},
    {name: 'Sam', id: 3, data: 'B'}
  ],
  [
    {name: 'Bob', id: 1, data: 'C'}
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way of doing this without needing to create nested loops.

---

### Update Edit 2

Playing around in LinqPad using the default DemoDB it comes with an using the orders table for test data using the EmployeeID, the following seems to work:

```
// make a copy of the orders table so as not to delete any actual data
List<Orders> lst = Orders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderID).ToList();

int x = 0; // only used as a counter for the console output

while (lst.Any()) {
    Console.WriteLine($"List has {lst.Count()} orders");
    
    List<Orders> lst1 = lst.OrderBy(x => x.OrderID).GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
    
    Console.WriteLine($"List {x++} has {lst1.Count()} orders");
    
    lst = lst.Where(x => !lst1.Contains(x)).ToList();
    
    Console.Write(lst1);
}
```

Can anyone improve on this performance wise?

Comment: and what did you try? What is ypur problem on a loop? You **will** need one, either explictely by code or implicitely by using LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to GoodNightNerdPride's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771007/11178549) and RandRandom's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770578/11178549), but without using an external dependency, and without using LINQ with side-effects:

```
UserApplication[] source = new[]
{
    new UserApplication() { Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Data = "A"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 2, Name = "Jim", Data = "A"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 3, Name = "Sam", Data = "A"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Data = "B"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Data = "C"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 3, Name = "Sam", Data = "B"},
    new UserApplication() { Id = 4, Name = "Bob", Data = "A"} // Different Bob
};

List<UserApplication>[] lists = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => (Item: x, Ordinal: i)))
    .GroupBy(entry => entry.Ordinal)
    .Select(g => g.Select(entry => entry.Item).ToList())
    .ToArray();

foreach (var list in lists)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",
        list.Select(a => $"(#{a.Id} {a.Name}: {a.Data})")));
}
```

The first `GroupBy` groups the applications by `Id`, and then an `Ordinal` is assigned to the applications that are grouped together. Then the groups are flattened, and a second `GroupBy` groups again the applications by `Ordinal`. Finally the `Ordinal` is discarded.

Output:

```xml
(#1 Bob: A), (#2 Jim: A), (#3 Sam: A), (#4 Bob: A)
(#1 Bob: B), (#3 Sam: B)
(#1 Bob: C)
```

The `UserApplication` class used in the example:

```
class UserApplication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach... I'm not a fan of adding external packages if I don't have to.

Comment: Thanks @StuartMc for accepting my answer! To be fair though I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Transpose.cs) of MoreLinq's `Transpose` operator, and it looks that it may be more efficient than my suggested solution. That's because it streams lazily the regrouped data one at a time, instead of producing all the groupings eagerly. I doubt that the advantage in efficiency will be significant in most usage scenarios, but I ought to point it out nonetheless. 

Comment: It should also be mentioned that the MoreLinq library has an excellent reputation. Most of its "meat" has been coded by the [Chuck Norris](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jon-skeet-the-chuck-norris-of-programming-ee5781c7e18a/) of programming, Jon Skeet himself!

Comment: @StuartMc, if you really don't want to add MoreLINQ to your project then you should definitely implement `Transpose()` for yourself or copy & paste it from MoreLINQ's sources. Doing `GroupBy()` twice is not only inefficient; it's also less clear, because `Transpose()` is a very well-known operation, readers can easily visualize in their heads to understand what the code does.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and comments... I have no problem adding things like MoreLINQ in general.  In this case it's just an update to an existing (old) application and this is quite possibly the only time it would be used.  So it's more a point of not adding it for the use of a single piece of functionality.  I will most definitely keep MoreLINQ in mind for future projects though.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to group all your items by `id` and then *transpose* the groupings.

So (when only considering the `id`s) the list `[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4]` is turned into a list of groupings:

```
[
  [1, 1, 1],
  [2],
  [3, 3],
  [4]
]
```

Which then is transposed (rows become columns and vice versa):

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1,    3   ],
  [1         ]
]
```

With the [MoreLINQ package](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Transpose.cs) you can do that easily:

```cs
using System.Linq; // for GroupBy()
using MoreLinq;    // for Transpose()

// ...

var result = new[] {
        new { name = "Bob", id = 1, data = "A" },
        new { name = "Jim", id = 2, data = "A" },
        new { name = "Sam", id = 3, data = "A" },
        new { name = "Bob", id = 1, data = "B" },
        new { name = "Bob", id = 1, data = "C" },
        new { name = "Sam", id = 3, data = "B" },
        new { name = "Bob", id = 4, data = "Notice this is a different Bob" }
    }
    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Transpose();
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XPKVHo):

```
{id: 1, name: Bob, data: A}, {id: 2, name: Jim, data: A}, {id: 3, name: Sam, data: A}, {id: 4, name: Bob, data: Notice this is a different Bob}
{id: 1, name: Bob, data: B}, {id: 3, name: Sam, data: B}
{id: 1, name: Bob, data: C}
```

The performance should be good enough. An optimized implementation without LINQ is always faster, but big O complexity will be the same anyway. IMHO clarity and brevity clearly beat a micro-optimized implementation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var array = new List<Example>
{
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Jim", Id = 2, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "B" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "C" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "B" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 4, Data = "Notice this is a different Bob" },
};

var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var x = array.GroupBy(x =>
{
    dict.TryGetValue(x.Id, out var value);
    dict[x.Id] = ++value;
    return value;
}).ToList();
```

If I am not mistaken, it is basically @Amadan 's idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GroupBy()` method from LINQ to group collection by property you need. Try the following code:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

var array = new[]
{
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Jim", Id = 2, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "B" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "C" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "B" },
};

var groups = array.GroupBy(x => x.Data);
```

**UPDATE** In order to gain the requested result I ended with this code:

```
var array = new List<Example>
{
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Jim", Id = 2, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "A" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "B" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 1, Data = "C" },
    new Example{ Name = "Sam", Id = 3, Data = "B" },
    new Example{ Name = "Bob", Id = 4, Data = "Notice this is a different Bob" },
};

// group entries by name so we know we will have [nameCount,cols] dimensional result
var groups = array.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToArray());

// Initialize result as multidimensional list
var output = groups.Select(x => new List<Example>()).ToList();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    int j = 0; // <= index of item in output
    for (int i = 0; i < group.Value.Length; i++)
    {
        // check if output[j] doesn't contain item with same name and id
        if (output[j].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == group.Value[i].Name && x.Id == group.Value[i].Id) == null)
        {
            output[j].Add(group.Value[i]);
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            i--;
        }
        
        if (j == output.Count) j = 0; // <= reset counter
    }
}
```

Comment: The grouping by `Data` in OP's post is incidental. The requirement is that in each group each `name` appears only once - `Data` is not the part of the requirement.

Comment: @Amadan is absolutely correct... the Data is not an issue and could be the same for each application.  The Id would be a unique id of Each person and the names could be the same but have a different ID... I used the above to try make it easy to read.

Comment: @StuartMc, anyway you can use this method to reach your goal or update your question with a closest to live data example so we could provide better solution

Comment: @SergeyAnisimov, I've updated my question with a little more info.  Using your example but grouping by ID instead of Data, I would get a list with 3 Bob applications, 2 Sam applications, 1 Jim application and 1 for the new Bob with a different ID.  But I need 3 lists of applications that all have just one application per person (ID)... as in the example I gave.

Comment: @StuartMc, thank you for updating it. Not sure that you can make it without nested loops. I will update my answer later

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Dictionary` of names to integers. For each application, see how many applications that person you saw so far (0 if not yet there); insert that application in that row of the result (creating the row if it doesn't yet exist) (e.g. if count of `Bob` is 0, insert into 0th row), then increment the count (e.g. we've now seen 1 `Bob`; next `Bob` would go into the 1st row). Complexity is O(N).